# Programitically adding URIs for Authorized redirect URIs in OAuth 2.0 Client IDs For GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, devops, gcloud

I am trying to find out a way to programmatically adding the URIS for Authorized redirect URIs in OAuth 2.0 Client IDs  In GCP , Either a python package or gcloud .
Tried finding the docs and not able to find any . Can some one tell me if there is any way to do that instead of manually adding that.

[image]

[image]

Please find the locations in GCP where i want to add the urls .

Comment: Checkout this package, might be of help to your situation https://github.com/evansmwendwa/python-socialite

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't, i.e. there's no public API for this functionality.

Comment: Is there any public documentation or open issue or feature request for this? It took me a while to find this page but can't seem to find anything official. I am sure this is 100% correct though.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Perhaps file an issue on Google's issue track for GCP identity|security: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187167

Comment: A good way to find Google APIs is to use APIs Explorer. With few exceptions, if an API is not listed there, it's not available (from Google). https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer

Comment: I have created a case for exposing the api , tracked under https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190460278

Comment: @leeman24 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35898945